# XQuery != operator with a sequence

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am running into the following problem, and syntax wise I am not sure why I am getting the results that I am getting.

I have the following FLOWR expression:

```
(: example 1 :)
for $attr in $node/@*
where $attr/fn:local-name != ("src", "type", "id")
return $attr
```

The English version of this is in my mind is: `Get me all the attributes that are not src, type, or id`.

However, when I run this, every attribute gets returned, including `src, type, and id`.  When I change my `where` statement to just have one element, `where $attr/fn:local-name != ("src")`, then this works as expected - all the attributes except for `src` gets returned. Weird, it works when comparing to one element, but not to three.

If I reverse my logic, and make a statement like this:

```
(: example 2 :)
for $attr in $node/@*
where $attr/fn:local-name = ("src", "type", "id")
return $attr
(: difference is = instead of != :)
```

then I also I get the results I expect, which are just the 3 attributes `"src", "type", and "id"`, and nothing else.

So, back to my original case, in order to get it to work the way that I am expecting, I must use the following statement:

```
(: example 3 :)
for $attr in $node/@*
where fn:not($attr/fn:local-name = ("src", "type", "id"))
return $attr
```

And this returns all the attributes except for `src, type, and id`.

Why is this happening the way that it is happening?  In my mind, **example 1** and **example 3** should do the same thing.  However, I cannot get **example 1** to work the way that I am expecting it to.

The xPath equivalent of my question looks similar to:

```
$node/@*[fn:not(./fn:local-name(.) = ("src", "type", "id"))]
```

Can anybody explain where my thinking is faulty?

I am using `xquery version "1.0-ml"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is when you think that you reverse the logic by changing `!=` into `=`.  But the are not the opposite of each other.

`=` is true when any item in the left-hand side sequence is equal to any item in the right-hand side sequence.  `!=` is true when any item in the left-hand side sequence is different from any item in the right-hand side sequence.

```
( 1, 2, 3 ) = ( 1, 5 )  (: true :)
( 1, 2, 3 ) = ( )       (: false :)
( 1, 2, 3 ) != ( 1, 5 ) (: true :)
```

The opposite of `x=y`, as you found out, is `not(x=y)`.

When the left-hand side sequence or the right-hand side sequence is a singleton, then by definition `not(x=y)` equals `x!=y`.

Answer (score 3):

When you say `$x != (1, 2, 3)` that translates to `$x does not equal 1, 2, and 3`. The `!=` operator will return true if any of the values on the left and right hand sides are not equal, so if `$x` is `1`, this still returns `true` because `$x` doesn't equal `2` or `3`.